# VBA: Slow filtering due to comments/notes

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with an excel sheet (15k rows, 20 columns) and the VBA code is supposed to do filtering.
About 7500 of the cells contain a comment/note.
The macro runs about 30 seconds on the code, but whenever I remove all the comments (home>edit>remove comments) and rerun, it is instant. Any simple filtering on this data takes very long because of the comments.

Is there some command/option in VBA to disable/ignore the comments for the time a macro is being run and return them once complete? Or any other alternative?

Comment: Have you tried disabling screen updating?

Comment: Yes, same goes for calculation and other options usually advised.

Comment: @Arkadiw can you show us your work? Your goal and a sample data so we can help you?

Comment: Its just an excel with data of clients. You can simply create random data, add notes to it and run a vba filter.